# Castle ActiveRecord: one-to-one

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle, one-to-one

While playing around with one-to-one associations in castle activerecord I stumbled upon the following problem:

I'm trying to model a one-to-one relationship (user-userprofile in this case). I already learned that this may not be a best practice, but let's ignore that for a moment (I'm still trying to understand what's going on).

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class TestUser : ActiveRecordBase<TestUser>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.GuidComb)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


}

[ActiveRecord]
public class TestUserProfile : ActiveRecordBase<TestUserProfile>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.GuidComb)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(Cascade = CascadeEnum.All, Fetch = FetchEnum.Join)]
    public TestUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I would expect the following code to save a user with profile, yielding the same Id in the database:

```
    [Test]
    public void save_profile_saves_user()
    {
        var profile = new TestUserProfile
        {
            User = new TestUser()
        };

        profile.Save();

    }
```

The actual result however is that both objects are saved with a different key. Am I missing something??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. The PrimaryKeyType of the side of the relation where OneToOne is defined should have a PrimaryKey of PrimaryKeyType.Foreign:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class TestUserProfile : ActiveRecordBase<TestUserProfile>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Foreign)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [OneToOne(Cascade = CascadeEnum.All, Fetch = FetchEnum.Join)]
    public TestUser User { get; set; }

 }
```

Back to reading the docs more thoroughly...